# Use of that versus which

Tags: grammar

My wife is learning English and she wrote the following sentence.

"When highlighting the large profit losses, the author identified a decrease in sales at Tasty Cream that is the only ice cream store in town."

She believes that this sentence is grammatically correct. However, I believe that using "Tasty Cream, which is the only ice cream store in town" or "Tasty Cream, the only ice cream store in town" is grammatically correct. Can someone help to explain which usage is correct and why? Thank you!

Comment: With respect to your [note](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/349186/142322) among the answers below, here is the [edit] link for you to make corrections to the question directly.

Answer (score 0):

For all practical purposes they are interchangeable, especially in British English. The rule, which is actually quite arbitrary, is this:

Use 'which' when introducing a nonrestrictive clause; use 'that' when introducing a restrictive clause.

Again, regardless of the rule, they are practically interchangeable and the vast, vast majority of people use them as such.

Source: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825043635/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/that-or-which)

Comment: You've got that backwards.

Comment: Yeah, was a pretty harmful mistype.